# Getting error "QSQLITE driver not loaded" when running Qt program in Virtual Machine

Tags: c++, sql, qt, sqlite, qt4

I have a Qt4 program, which only opens a Qt database:

```
QSqlDatabase db;
db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
db.setDatabaseName(fileName);
if (!db.open()) {
    qDebug() << db.lastError().text();
}
```

I run the program from Explorer, and inside the directory I have only the exe and the DLLs it needs: Test.exe
QtCore4.dll
QtSql4.dll
QtGui4.dll

The same exe and DLLs work when executed on my own computer, but fail when executed in a Virtual Machine with these errors:

```
[2784] QSqlDatabase: QSQLITE driver not loaded
[2784] QSqlDatabase: available drivers:
```

And `db.lastError().text()` returns "Driver not loaded Driver not loaded" (yes, it's repeated twice).

Why is it working on my computer? If there is a dependency missing, I assume it would fail on my own computer too, because it looks only in its own directory for all the DLLs that it needs. Obviously there is a **dependency that it finds on my computer, but not on the virtual machine**, and it must be looking for it elsewhere (not only in the directory where the exe is).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should also place `qsqlite4.dll` in a directory named `sqldrivers` alongside the executable.

Comment: Do you have any idea why it was working on my computer? Was qsqlite4.dll in the PATH?

Comment: I think the path for plugins are stored in an environment variable when installing Qt and the application has access to it.